# how set the permissions for cancan gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, cancan, cancancan

please help solve the problem. i try set the permissions after install 'cancan' and 'cancancan' gems.

schema.rb:

```
create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "roles_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "role_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  ................................................................
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  def role?(role)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
  end     
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

app/models/ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :manager
      can :manage, :review
      cannot :manage, :user
    elsif user.role? :user
      cannot :manage, :all
    end   
  end
end
```

i filled my roles table follow values:

```
id    name  
0     user
1     manager
2     admin
```

i filled my join table 'roles_users' follow values:

```
role_id       user_id
2             2
1             3
0             1
```

but after run application permissions is no effect. the problem is that managers can change info for all users. it is not right. please help to fix it

ps:

```
my user controller:
class UserController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

after manager change info about user via adminpanel, console output follow:

```
Started GET "/admin/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-19 20:53:47 +0300
Processing by Admin::UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "active_admin_comments" WHERE "active_admin_comments"."resource_type" = ? AND "active_admin_comments"."resource_id" = ? AND "active_admin_comments"."namespace" = ?  [["resource_type", "User"], ["resource_id", "1"], ["namespace", "admin"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "active_admin_comments" WHERE "active_admin_comments"."resource_type" = ? AND "active_admin_comments"."resource_id" = ? AND "active_admin_comments"."namespace" = ?  [["resource_type", "User"], ["resource_id", "1"], ["namespace", "admin"]]
  Rendered /home/kalinin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bundler/gems/activeadmin-893b46c6530c/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb (316.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 321ms (Views: 318.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `.camelize` call in your `role?` method, since all your roles in db are stored in lower-case (`manager`) and not in camelCase (`ManagerOfTheApplication`).

It seems your `Admin::UsersController` is located in `active_admin`. Try to enable [`active_admin` and `can_can` integration](http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using-the-cancan-adapter):

```
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
```

Look into the link above on the details.

Comment: Can you try in rails console: `User.find(2).role?(:admin)` and some other role, for example, `User.find(2).role?(:manager)`

Comment: in console User.find(2).role?(:admin) return TRUE

Comment: Well, I believe your role checking code should work fine then. Maybe it's some controller issue?

Comment: alex, i added new info into main question. in block 'ps:'

Comment: You've shown me `UserController`, but your console says about `Admin::UsersController`.

Comment: but controller controllers/admin/user_controller.rb is not exist in my application